# How do I Filter Key:Value pairs from JSON data in DynamoDB query?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `DynamoDB` with the following structure:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------+
| PK    | SK               | INFO          |
+-------+------------------+---------------+
| Event | DateTime_EventID | {JSON Object} |
+-------+------------------+---------------+
| "     | "                | "             |
+-------+------------------+---------------+
| "     | "                | "             |
+-------+------------------+---------------+
```

After doing a `QUERY` for the range of events I want, I then want to `FILTER` the results based on a `KEY:VALUE` value pair in a `JSON` object stored in the `INFO` column.

What's the best way to do that? Filter Attribute String Contains ???

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You can do it with `FilterExpression` , something will be like `FilterExpression: "#info.#author = :author_to_filter"`

Comment: if you are going to do it on a larger scale, elastic search is a better tool than dynamodb.